# How to use MongoDB Java driver to group by dayOfYear on ISODate attributes?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

How to use mongodb java driver to compare dayOfYear of two ISODate objects?

Here are my docs

```
{"name": "hello", "count": 4, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-02T02:00:35.098Z")}
{"name": "hello", "count": 5, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-02T02:00:35.098Z")}
{"name": "goodbye", "count": 6, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-01T02:00:35.098Z")}
{"name": "foo", "count": 6, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-02T02:00:35.098Z")}
```

I want to compare the day in "TIMESTAMP" to perform some aggregation

```
 Bson match = Aggregates.match(eq("name": "hello"));
 Bson group = Aggregates.group(new Document("name", "$name"), Accumulators.sum("total", 1));

collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, group))
```

Now I am not sure how to do this aggregation for all the records that belongs to particular day?

so my expected result for "2017-10-02" is

`[{"_id": {"name":"hello"}, "total": 9}, {"_id": {"name":"foo"}, "total": 6}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following documents:

```
{"name": "hello", "count": 4, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-02T02:00:35.098Z")}
{"name": "hello", "count": 5, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-02T02:00:35.098Z")}
{"name": "goodbye", "count": 6, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-01T02:00:35.098Z")}
{"name": "foo", "count": 6, "TIMESTAMP": ISODate("2017-10-02T02:00:35.098Z")}
```

The following command ...

```
db.getCollection('dayOfYear').aggregate([

    // project dayOfYear as an attribute
    { $project: { name: 1, count: 1, dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$TIMESTAMP" } } },

    // match documents with dayOfYear=275
    { $match: { dayOfYear: 275 } },

    // sum the count attribute for the selected day and name
    { $group : { _id : { name: "$name" }, total: { $sum: "$count" } } } 

])
```

... will return:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "foo"
    },
    "total" : 6
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "hello"
    },
    "total" : 9
}
```

I *think* this meets the requirement expressed in your OP.

Here's the same command expressed using the MongoDB Java driver:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("stackoverflow").getCollection("dayOfYear");

Document project = new Document("name", 1)
        .append("count", 1)
        .append("dayOfYear", new Document("$dayOfYear", "$TIMESTAMP"));

Document dayOfYearMatch = new Document("dayOfYear", 275);

Document grouping = new Document("_id", "$name").append("total", new Document("$sum", "$count"));

AggregateIterable<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$project", project),
        new Document("$match", dayOfYearMatch),
        new Document("$group", grouping)
));

for (Document document : documents) {
    logger.info("{}", document.toJson());
}
```

**Update** based on this comment:

> One of the problems with project is that it only include fields you specify . The above input is just an example. I have 100 fields in my doc I can't sepecify every single one so if I use project I have to specify all 100 fields in addition to "dayOfYear" field. – user1870400 11 mins ago

You can use the following command to return the same output but without a `$project` stage:

```
db.getCollection('dayOfYear').aggregate([
    // ignore any documents which do not match dayOfYear=275
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
             if: { $eq: [ { $dayOfYear: "$TIMESTAMP" }, 275 ] },
             "then": "$$KEEP",
             "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},

    // sum the count attribute for the selected day
    { $group : { _id : { name: "$name" }, total: { $sum: "$count" } } } 

])
```

Here's that command in its 'Java form':

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("stackoverflow").getCollection("dayOfYear");

Document redact = new Document("$cond", new Document("if", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(new Document("$dayOfYear", "$TIMESTAMP"), 275)))
        .append("then", "$$KEEP")
        .append("else", "$$PRUNE"));

Document grouping = new Document("_id", "$name").append("total", new Document("$sum", "$count"));

AggregateIterable<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$redact", redact),
        new Document("$group", grouping)
));

for (Document document : documents) {
    logger.info("{}", document.toJson());
}
```

**Note:** Depending on the size of your collection/your non functional requirements/etc you may want to consider the performance of these solutions and either (a) add a match stage before you start projecting/redacting or (b) extract dayOfYear into its own attribute so that you can avoid this complexity entirely.

Comment: I cant see dayOfYear function in mongodb Java driver.

Comment: @user1870400 There is no `dayOfYear` function in the Java driver but if you can confirm that the output from the command I supplied in my answer **is** your desired output then I can update my answer with the 'Java form' of that command.

Comment: What I was looking for is do the aggregation "sum" for a particular day so I need to pass a filter that filters out all the document that doesnt belong to a given day. For example, I want to sum all the documents that have match name hello and the day "2017-10-02".  If the timestamp has any other date then I don't want it to be taken into the account for the aggregation.

Comment: Now I'm a bit lost :) in your eaerlier comment you wrote: `I want to sum all the documents that have match name hello and the day "2017-10-02"` but the desired output in your updated question does not focus on a specific name at all. In addition, the desired output in your updated question shows sum(count) for `name=hello` (i.e. 5 + 4 = 9) but the equivalent value for `name=foo` is 1 which is not a sum at all but rather a count of the number of instances of `foo`.

Comment: now you can see I am grouping by name and summing the "counts" for all the records that match "2017-10-02".

Comment: @user1870400 I have updated the answer with a solution which produces the desired output from your question

Comment: I already accepted your answer. One of the problems with project is that it only include fields you specify . The above input is just an example. I have 100 fields in my doc I can't sepecify every single one so if I use project I have to specify all 100 fields in addition to "dayOfYear" field.

Comment: But you end up grouping the results and your group only includes `name` and `count` so (based on the desired output your provided in your question) you don't need the other 100+ fields.

Comment: True but  I usually group by more than 1 field or 2 field. I group by 30 fields so those fields are necessary to pass down the pipeline.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a solution which does not use `$project`. Depending on the size of your collection/your non functional requirements/etc you may want to consider the performance of these solutions and either (a) add a match stage before you start projecting/redacting or (b) extract dayOfYear into its own attribute so that you can avoid this complexity entirely.

Comment: Perfect!! Appreciate a ton!!